# Django Unittest doesn't load fixtures

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-unittest

Django testrunner is not loading fixtures out of media app fixtures/ directory.
How can I debug it - find if it's looking for my fixtures and where?

(Python 2.7.1, Django 1.3.1)

My app (app_label=media) directory structure:

```
media/fixtures/
media/fixtures/media.json
media/fixtures/auth.json
media/tests/
media/tests/__init__
media/tests/general.py (v---- test below)
```

general.py

```
from django.utils import unittest
from apps.webmachinist.media.models import *

class GalleryItemFormTest(unittest.TestCase):

    fixtures = ['media.json','auth.json']
[...]
```

Traceback:

```
./manage.py test media --verbosity=2
Creating test database for alias 'default' (':memory:')...
Syncing...
Creating tables ...
Creating table auth_permission
[...]
Creating table tagging_taggeditem
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Migrating...
Running migrations for media:
 - Migrating forwards to 0002_auto__del_field_image_image__add_field_image_file__del_field_video_vid.
 > media:0001_initial
 > media:0002_auto__del_field_image_image__add_field_image_file__del_field_video_vid
 - Loading initial data for media.
No fixtures found.
Running migrations for portfolio:
 - Migrating forwards to 0001_initial.
 > portfolio:0001_initial
 - Loading initial data for portfolio.
No fixtures found.

Synced:
 > django.contrib.auth
 > django.contrib.contenttypes
 > django.contrib.sessions
 > django.contrib.sites
 > django.contrib.messages
 > django.contrib.staticfiles
 > django.contrib.admin
 > django.contrib.admindocs
 > south
 > sorl.thumbnail
 > tagging

Migrated:
 - apps.webmachinist.media
 - apps.webmachinist.portfolio
No fixtures found.
```

Comment: Where are your fixture files located?  Django only searches 'fixtures' directories in each app.  Can you summarize your app directory structure and show where the fixture files are?

Comment: Please **update** the question with the additional details.  Please do not add comments to a question which you own.  You own it.  You can make it complete, correct and consistent.  Please **update** the question and then delete the hard-to-read comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `django.test.TestCase` instead of `unittest.TestCase`.

Answer (score 3):

This might save someone an extra search or two...

```
from django.test import TestCase

class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['myfixture.json']
```